# Mysql read value from same table using reseller id

Tags: mysql

I have the following table:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
| id | user    | pass   | nick    | reseller |
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
|  1 | admin   | 125854 | X-Admin | 2        |
|  2 | user256 | 123321 | User-256| NULL     |
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
```

I need to get this from query:

```
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
| id | user    | pass   | nick    | reseller |
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
|  1 | admin   | 125854 | X-Admin | User-256 |
|  2 | user256 | 123321 | User-256| NULL     |
+----+---------+--------+---------+----------+
```

So that i can use tbl.reseller in my ajax html web page...i try using this query:

```
SELECT g1.nick
FROM resellers g1, resellers g2
INNER JOIN g2 ON g2.reseller=g1.id;
```

But i im getting this error:

```
ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'g2'
```

I need to get reseller value and using id get nick to display at output..so in this example i get for id 1 reseller value 2 what is the id 2 in table and read value id 2 for nick column and display it as reseller.

As you can see i need to INNER JOIN from same table so i read i need to use alias (g1 g2 or AS?) but i don't know how to do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.user,
    r1.pass,
    r1.nick,
    r2.user
FROM resellers r1
INNER JOIN resellers r2
    ON r1.reseller = r2.id
```

As for why your current query is wrong, you are actually self joining *twice*.  The following represents a single self join:

```
SELECT g1.nick
FROM resellers g1, resellers g2
```

This is an old-style implicit join, which has been replaced with the explicit join syntax I used in my answer.  Then, you do a *second* self join:

```
INNER JOIN g2 ON g2.reseller=g1.id;
```

The reason for the non unique alias error is that MySQL can't figure out to which of the two joined tables you are referring.

Comment: Thanks..i try the query and getting this error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 't2.user' in 'field list'....i will try to find whay t2 table does not exist..thanks..

Comment: @John Sorry, that should be `r2.user` :-)

Comment: Thanks..you saved me a couple of hours..i im trying this 4hours today with alias inner join using WHERE but i could not get this..uisng your query above i get this query right and thanks...